# syntax error related to this code. Have tried looking it up but not helping

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to create a resistance calculator program but I am getting a syntax error.

```
print("Welcome to resistance calculator!!!")
import time
import math
time.sleep(2)
powersource=int(input("How many volts is your battery?"))
time.sleep(2)
convertquestion=input("Is your amps in milaamps?")
time.sleep(2)
if convertquestion=="yes" or "Yes":
    step1=int(input("How many milaaps do you have?"))
    step2=step1*.001
    amps=step2
    time.sleep(2)
    forwardvolt=float((input("What is your forward voltage?"))
    step_1=powersource-forwardvolt
    step_2=step_1/amps
    time.sleep(2)
    print("You will need a resister value of:", step_2)
else:
    firststep=int(input("How many amps do you have?"))
    time.sleep(2)
    secondstep=float(input("What is your forward voltage?"))
    time.sleep(2)
    thirdstep=powersource-secondstep
    forthstep=thirdstep/firststep
    print("You will need a resister value of:", forthstep)
```

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: What is the syntax error you're getting, and what line are you getting it on? You have that information available to you, on the screen right in front of you. There is absolutely no reason for you to not include it in your question. You're asking us to help you solve **your problem** - give us the information you have available to help us to help you. Especially when you have to do nothing to get it because it's right in front of your eyes, on your screen, where it can be easily copied and pasted into your question.

Comment: missing closing parentheses, also your `if` statement is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an extra parentheses at line 14. Change it to this:

```
forwardvolt=float(input("What is your forward voltage?"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not see that extra one. Simple fix thank goodness.

Comment: So sense I am new to this site and my program now works, how do I close this thread or do I just leave it?